# PHP - codeigniter URL not working without index.php - object not found

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, xampp

I am using codeigniter v3 for my website and I'm having problems redirecting from one page to another.

If I click the tab, the link shows `localhost:8080/IDS/view/decisiontree` and shows `Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server...`

If I edit the URL and make it `localhost:8080/IDS/index.php/view/decisiontree`, the site perfectly loads.

Here are my routes:

```
$route['view/decisiontree'] = 'data_controller/goto_decisiontree';
```

Here are the codes of the tab related:

```
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>view/decisiontree">Decision Tree</a></li>
```

Here is my data_controller:

```
public function goto_decisiontree(){
    $data['page'] = "2";

    $this->load->view('decisiontree_page', $data);
}
```

And here is my `config.php`:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8080/IDS';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Here's my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And note, I'm using Codeigniter V3.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Just a note at the end of base url put forward slash `/`  `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8080/IDS/';`

Comment: Are you using wamp or xampp etc?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

Open `config.php` and do following replaces

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php"
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = ""
```

In some cases the default setting for `uri_protocol` does not work properly. Just replace

```
$config['uri_protocol'] ="AUTO"
```

by

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```

**HTACCESS**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Hope it helps .

Answer (score 0):

Try this htaccess in main directory of your codeIgniter project. It seems to work fine in xampp and wamp.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8080/IDS/';
$config['index_page'] = "";
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

All ways remember that you should have first letter of file name and class as upper case the rest lower case. [refer](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#let-s-try-it-hello-world)

More htaccess examples [here](https://github.com/riwakawebsitedesigns/htaccess_for_codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

*Note: I'm on Ubuntu, so the paths here may change if you are on another distro.*

I tried all .htaccess suggestions and none seemed to work, so I started thinking that was not the problem. And then it hit me, the `apache.conf` file. Doesn't matter the .htaccess you have, if that file is restricting the override, there's nothing you can do.

So i went to `/etc/apache2/` and edited the `apache2.conf` file adding this:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/your-project-folder>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Also change `$config['index_page'] = index;` to `$config['index_page'] = '';` in `application/config/config.php` as said above.

Btw, my .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(application) - [F,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

And don't forget to restart apache.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to set the index_page blank in config.php file

$config['index_page']= "";

Also please change the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below in your .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# If your website begins from a folder e.g localhost/my_project then 
# you have to change it to: RewriteBase /my_project/
# If your site begins from the root e.g. example.local/ then
# let it as it is
RewriteBase /

# Protect application and system files from being viewed when the index.php is missing
RewriteCond $1 ^(application|system|private|logs)

# Rewrite to index.php/access_denied/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/access_denied/$1 [PT,L]

# Allow these directories and files to be displayed directly:
RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|public|assets|css|js|images)

# No rewriting
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [PT,L]

# Rewrite to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

For more detail, you can visit [here](https://www.web-and-development.com/codeigniter-remove-index-php-minimize-url/)